# df shows low disk space. It includes a directory which uses mount --bind for chroot sftp

Tags: mount, disk-space-utilization, chroot, df, du

I've setup a chroot environment for sftp access (sftp only, no shell).

The sftp user needs rw access to a host directory. I mounted it via /etc/fstab
`/var/www/html  /home/sftp-user/jail/html   none    bind    0   0`

When I do `df -h` I get the following output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
[...]
/dev/sda1        75G   65G  7,7G  90% /
[...]
```

For `du -sh` I get the following:

```
# du -sh /* 2> /dev/null | sort -h
0   /bin
0   /dev
0   /initrd.img
0   /lib
0   /lib32
0   /lib64
0   /libx32
0   /proc
0   /sbin
0   /sys
0   /vmlinuz
4,0K    /mnt
4,0K    /opt
4,0K    /srv
8,0K    /media
16K /lost+found
44K /tmp
4,4M    /etc
52M /boot
81M /run
1,4G    /usr
13G /root
15G /home
36G /var
```

But the 15GB in home only come from the jail

```
# du -sh /home/sftp-user/jail/* 2> /dev/null | sort -h
15G /home/sftp-user/jail/html
```

My understanding of the mount was, that it was more like a symlink, so the disk space is not really used. Is it?

I'm pretty sure I tried to solve that with a symlink first, but something wasn't working that's why I'm using mount now. Unfortunately I forgot what exactly the problem with a symlink was. I think the sftp user had no access to the host folder through that symlink.

Is there a better solution either to get the symlink to work or to show the real used disk space?

Edit for clarification:
I don't get why `/dev/sda1` seems so full. `/var/www/html` and `/home/sftp-user/jail/html` are both on `/dev/sda1`. I have nothing else in my `/home`, only that mount. So practically the real size of it should be only some bytes.

So when adding up the sizes of `/usr`, `/root`, `/home` and `/var` (1,4+13+15+36) I get ~65G. But the actual location of the 15GB of the `/home`-files is in `/var`, so the used disk space which df shows should only be ~50G (1,4+13+36).

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your question is. You seem to be surprised that `/home` has 15GB. That is so because by default, `du` doesn't care for mount points. It just goes down the filesystem tree until the leaves (i.e., regular files) and sums up their sizes. You can try the `-x` option; it should make it stop at mount points.

You also seem to be worried or surprised about the space usage on `/dev/sda1`. You can remove files or extend that partition (if there is room on `/dev/sda`), but the information you provide is not sufficient to help you.

I think your bind mount is a good solution.

Comment: Hi berndbausch, thanks for your fast answer. I added an edit to my OP. `-x` is described as "skip directories on different file systems", but it's both on `/dev/sda1`. That was probably the missing piece in my question.